# I am using angular 2 angular-cli and try to use ng2-datetime,but it give error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'jQuery' of undefined"

Tags: jquery, node.js, angular, angular2-cli

I installed the angular2 cli using command "npm install -g angular-cli" and I want to use ng2-datetime in my project.But it is showing error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'jQuery' of undefined".How can I use ng2-datetime in angular2 cli.
Here is link for ng2-datetime [enter link description here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-datetime)

I want to include above ng2-datetime.

I got the following error.
[image]

Here is my app.module

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'; import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'; import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http'; import { Ng2PlayRoutingModule } from './app.routing'; import { AppComponent } from './app.component'; import { GridviewComponent } from './dashboard/gridview/gridview.component'; import { DetailsComponent } from './dashboard/details/details.component'; import { Logincomponent } from './login/login.component'; import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component'; import { DrilldownComponent } from './dashboard/drilldown/drilldown.component'; import { DropdownModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap'; import { WorkbenchComponent } from './workbench/workbench.component'; import { TasksComponent } from './workbench/tasks/tasks.component'; import { TaskdetailsComponent } from './workbench/taskdetails/taskdetails.component'; import { TopnavComponent } from './shared/topnav/topnav.component'; import { FieldfilterPipe } from './shared/pipes/fieldfilter.pipe'; import { LimitFirstNPipe } from './dashboard/details/limit-first-n.pipe'; import { DatepickerDirective } from './shared/directives/datepicker.directive'; import { CalendarComponent } from './workbench/calendar/calendar.component'; import { DateFilterPipe } from './workbench/calendar/date-filter.pipe'; import { StopscrollDirective } from './shared/directives/stopscroll.directive'; import { CapitalizePipe } from './workbench/tasks/capitalize.pipe'; import { ConfirmDeleteDirective } from './shared/directives/confirm-delete.directive'; import { NumberPipe } from './shared/pipes/number.pipe'; import { FilterPipe } from './shared/pipes/filter.pipe'; import { PriorityPipe } from './shared/pipes/priority.pipe'; import { TopnextnavComponent } from './shared/topnextnav/topnextnav.component'; import { ActiveTabDirective } from './shared/topnextnav/active-tab.directive'; import { AtozPipe } from './shared/pipes/atoz.pipe'; import { ExcludePipe } from './shared/pipes/exclude.pipe'; import { AddtaskComponent } from './workbench/addtask/addtask.component'; import { MomentFormatPipe } from './shared/pipes/moment-format.pipe'; import { JqteEditorDirective } from './shared/directives/jqte-editor.directive'; import { MultiselectComponent } from './shared/md2-comp/multiselect/multiselect.component'; import { TimepickerComponent } from './shared/md2-comp/timepicker/timepicker.component'; import { JquerydatepickerDirective } from './shared/directives/jquerydatepicker.directive'; import { DatefilterPipe } from './shared/pipes/datefilter.pipe'; import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'; import { EventService } from './shared/service/event.service'; import { DrilldownService } from './dashboard/drilldown/drilldown.service'; import { ActiveTab } from './shared/directives/activetab.directive'; import { NKDatetime } from 'ng2-datetime/ng2-datetime';

//import { NKDatetimeModule } from 'ng2-datetime/ng2-datetime';


@NgModule({   declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    GridviewComponent,
    DetailsComponent,
    Logincomponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    DrilldownComponent,
    WorkbenchComponent,
    TasksComponent,
    TaskdetailsComponent,
    TopnavComponent,
    FieldfilterPipe,
    LimitFirstNPipe,
    DatepickerDirective,
    CalendarComponent,
    DateFilterPipe,
    StopscrollDirective,
    CapitalizePipe,
    ConfirmDeleteDirective,
    DateFilterPipe,
    NumberPipe,
    FilterPipe,
    PriorityPipe,
    TopnextnavComponent,
    ActiveTabDirective,
    AtozPipe,
    ExcludePipe,
    AddtaskComponent,
    MomentFormatPipe,
    JqteEditorDirective,
    MultiselectComponent,
    TimepickerComponent,
    JquerydatepickerDirective,
    JquerydatepickerDirective,
    ActiveTab,
    NKDatetime   ],   imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    Ng2PlayRoutingModule,
    DropdownModule   ],   // exports: [NKDatetime],   providers: [EventService,DrilldownService],   bootstrap: [AppComponent] }) export class AppModule { }
```

drilldown.component.html

```
 <main class="container">
        <section>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <datetime [timepicker]="false" [(ngModel)]="date"></datetime>
            </div>
        </section>

    </main>
```

Comment: Please also include the code from the DrilldownComponent.

Comment: Hi Tudor here is the link for drilldowncomponent.ts https://plnkr.co/edit/lV3hFC3SxoEBIjrG1OdR?p=preview

Comment: Have you include all dependencies from https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-datetime to your project?

Comment: Yes I used that and I use the bundled version from src/vendor/bootstrap-datepicker.

Comment: Hi Tudor,I got same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below steps:

- install `"ng2-datetime": "1.2.1"`
- install `"@types/jquery": "^2.0.33"`
- specify `"types": ["jquery"]` within *tsconfig.json*

This worked for me.